# How to find the first value in a range in MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube

I'm trying to create an SSAS calculated measure off of an inventory cube.  The underlying data contains an inventory_date, a product code, and some inventory values for the product for that date.  I am trying to create a measure which will return the first inventory value for the month, for the product (and overall).  I've seen people try to use the head function to no avail.  I've also just seen a reference to the openingperiod function, which seems to be exactly what I want, but it also isn't returning the correct value.  Both of them, FWIW, are returning the last value in the month rather than the first.

Here is a query that I am issuing:

```
select
    [Measures].[Qty On Hand EOD] on 0,
    {openingperiod([Inventory Date].[Calendar].[Month]):
[Inventory Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2018-06-25T00:00:00]
} on 1  
from [Daily Inventory]
```

This query returns for May 2018 the value of [Qty On Hand EOD] for May 31, rather than May 1, which is what I want.  What am I doing wrong?

FWIW, in the cube definition the AggregateFunction property for [Qty On Hand EOD] is set to LastNonEmpty (as opposed to Sum or Avg).  Could that play a role?

Comment: Could you add another measure `[Qty On Hand BOD]` in the cube that would be defined the same as `[Qty On Hand EOD]`, just use FirstNonEmpty as the aggregation function? That could already be the measure you want.

Comment: If I am drilling into, say, June 25, I want to see both the qty on hand EOD for June 25, and for June 1 for the month, Apr 1 for the quarter and Jan 1 for the year.  Defining anything as FirstNonEmpty will still just give me June 25 when I'm drilling to June 25.

Comment: If you finally want the value for a day, have you tried using `OpeningPeriod([Inventory Date].[Calendar].[Day])`?